# Obtaining Explicit Expressions for Tensor Contractions in xCoba

Tags: programming, tensors, xact

I Would like to know, how to reduce a general Tensor expression such as `Cd[-c][Cd[c][h[-a,-b]]]` (D'alambertian of some unknown two component tensor) to an explicit result in a Given Basis. i.e. Display the result fully contracted and only depending on the metric component functions, given in the chart, and the unknown components of h. I have only been successful in returning a result in terms of general christoffel symbols, although these should in principle be known for the given metric.

Here an Example for the Kasner Spacetime:

After defining the appropriate metric

```
DefTensor[h[-a, -b], Kasner]

Cd[-c][Cd[c][h[-a, -b]]]
% // ToBasis[B]
...
%//TraceBasisDummy// ToValues
```

This generates the output:

```
xAct`xTensor`Basis[{-a, -B}, e]   xAct`xTensor`Basis[{-b, -B}, f]  (
px/t[] + py/t[] + pz/t[]) (Cd[{0, B}][h[-e, -f]])+ 
xAct`xTensor`Basis[{-a, -B}, d]   xAct`xTensor`Basis[{-b, -B}, e](
Cd[{0, -B}][Cd[{0, B}][h[-d, -e]]]+...
)
```

Which is certainly correct, but I would like the covariant derivatives to be converted to Christoffel symbols and partial derivatives. For some reason, although they are known, the explicit expressions for the Christoffel symbols are only inserted in the very first term. `ChangeCovD[]` doesn't give a more explicit output either

Comment: Is this about Mathematica? Can you share any of your expressions in Mathematica code?

Comment: @Marco, [xCoba](http://xact.es/xCoba/) is a component of xAct, which is a rather extensive *Mathematica* project. Nevertheless, Max really should include example code and say something about what his desired solution might look like.